# Do I need to add "one" at the end of the sentence in the following case?

Tags: pronouns, grammaticality-in-context

As the river with the greatest amount of factories, it was to be the most polluted (one).

Comment: the sentence can be better reworded

Comment: You don't **need** "one"...

Comment: With or without the 'one', the sentence is a little awkward - particularly the word 'supposed' which implies 'was meant to be, but wasn't'. Can you please provide some more context i.e. the surrounding sentences?

Comment: OK - my comment now makes no sense :-) However, even with the word 'supposed' removed, it's still implied by your use of the past tense - "It was to be the most polluted". the implication here is that it designed (supposed) to be the most polluted, but wasn't. The sentence isn't clear in establishing whether or not the river was actually the most polluted.

Comment: Yeah... "became" would be clearer than "was to be" if it actually is the most polluted river.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As the river with the greatest amount of factories, it was to be the
>   most polluted (one).

"One" is optional.

But it is not clear what you mean with "was to be". "Was to be" puts us back in the past, looking forward:

**Why did you tell her about the gift? It was  to be a secret.**

The gift was [meant, intended, supposed] to remain a secret.

**As the river with the greatest number of factories, it *is|was* the most polluted.**